# playframework view engine, is it only groovy based still?

Tags: scala, playframework

I was reading how the playframework uses some groovy based view engine, and that view engine has some performance issues with it.

Is play still tied to this view engine or are there viable alternatives that ship with the framework (or don't require any substantial hacks to get it to work).

Also, I was reading how the playframework uses python for its command line code generation etc., can someone point me to the source code where that resides?

Answer (score 2):

- [Japid](http://playframework.org/modules/japid) is there for long time, it has best performance as it
  compiles template into byte code.
- Like Japid, [Rythm](http://playframework.org/modules/rythm) also
  compiles templates into byte code and is very fast also. It uses elegant .net Razor 
  syntax, and provides better Play!Framework integration. Check the
  full demo at [here](http://rythmengine.com), note it's running on GAE.
- There are some other template engines for Play!framework including [thymeleaf](http://www.playframework.org/modules/thymeleaf) and [cambridge](http://code.google.com/p/cambridge/wiki/UsingWithPlayFramework)

All above are for play-1.x, while Japid also provides play-2.x integration at [github](https://github.com/branaway/japid42).

The source code of the python stuff could be found at `${PLAY_ROOT}/framework/pym`.

Comment: so in play 2.0, the default view engine is the scala version?  does it have a name?

Comment: yes, the built-in template engine for play 2 is scala based. I think we just call it scala template engine for play2

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 3 template engines in [Play's modules](http://www.playframework.org/modules) and what's more they are there for long time now.

Also can be found at [playmodules.net](http://www.playmodules.net/module/list?nameFilter=template&versionFilter=1&inputTagFilter=)

Of course Play 2.0 brings new template engine based on Scala

Comment: cool! btw, is there a good demand for play consultants? or its still a very small niche?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Scala-based templates in Play! 2.x are definitely the way to go.

I've used plenty. But this is easily the best. It's also really tightly integrated with the Play! development process and the eclipse I'm running on top of it.